# Maximum Likelihood Estimation for Markov Chains

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, conditional-probability, markov-process

According to calculations in this paper
[https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/462/lectures/06/markov-mle.pdf](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ecshalizi/462/lectures/06/markov-mle.pdf)

[image]

The first line just uses the definition of conditional probability, but the second
line actually uses the Markov property — that the future is independent of the
past, given the present.

[image]

Then the equation **(4)** becomes equation **(5)**. I did not understand the logic of using $N_{ij}$ here. If I assume that $n=3$ ,then the equation **(4)** is

$$Pr(X_1,X_2,X_3) =  Pr(X_1=x_1)Pr(x_2|x_1)Pr(x_3|x_2) $$

[image]

Even if we use the $N_{ij}$ , it will always be equal to the $1$.So why do we need to use $N_{ij}$?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can see that by taking an example, say a MC with just $k=2$ states $\{1,2\}$. Then you run it for $n=10$-steps. Then the formula (4) is still valid but note that each $p_{ij}$ can not just occur once. The total number of transitions will be $9$ (assuming the initial time point is $1$). Therefore some of those $p_{ij}$'s must repeat and how many times? Precisely the number of times the MC jumps from $i$ to $j$.

More precisely, equation (3) or (4) are probabilities of a path visited by the MC. Take for example (in the $2$-states case) a path $(x_1=1,x_2=1,x_3=2,x_4=1,x_5=1,x_6=2,x_7=2,x_8=1,x_9=1,x_{10}=2)$. Then using equation (3) or (4) gives probability of this path is equal to
$$
Pr(X_1=1)p_{11}p_{12}p_{12}p_{21}p_{11}\ldots p_{12}= Pr(X_1=1)p_{11}^{3}p_{12}^{3}p_{21}^{2}p_{22}.
$$

Comment: If I run the equation(4) for $n=10$ , then It becomes $Pr(x_1) p_{x_{1},x_{2}} .... p_{x_{9},x_{10}}$. There is no repetition here

Comment: In your product, there are $9$ terms, whereas in the transition matrix $(2\times 2)$ there are only $4$ terms. Is it clear now?

Comment: I think It is the matrix you refer to right?
$\begin{bmatrix}
p_{11} & p_{12} \\
p_{21} & p_{22}
\end{bmatrix}$

Isn't it $p_{11}$ is the probability from state $1$ to state $1$ ? So I do not have this probability in my product.
Isn't it my product equal to the $p_{1,2} .... p_{9,10}$ ?

Could you write in more detail when you have time 
Thanks

Comment: @erdisayar See edited answer.

Comment: In your example, are the random variable $X$ is not state?
In this case, you have 10 states right ?

Can't we express your path example with the following way (without repetition)

$P(X_{1}=1) P(X_{2}=1 |X_{1}=1) P(X_{3}=2 |X_{2}=1) ... P(X_{10}=2 |X_{9}=1) $

In this case there is no repetition right ?

Comment: @erdisayar That being said in the example here, the vector $\mathbf{x}$ is a path. You can think of a fixed length path as being a random variable in its own right, but its space of values is not the same as the state space of the chain.

Comment: @erdisayar You expressed it perfectly. Then you are left to plug in the values from the transition matrix. In your case: $P(X_2|X_1) = p_{12}$, $P(X_3|X_2)=p_{23}$ etc. Therefore there are repetitions.